# read xml data in selenium

Tags: java, xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, properties-file

I want to read data from an XML file. I am using Java & Selenium WebDriver. I have found many solutions while researching. The problem is none seems to apply to my problem.

**My XML file is as such :**

```
<Enviroment>
    <Parameter>Test_Url</Parameter>
    <value>https://www.google.com</value>
    <Parameter>Distributed_Test</Parameter>
    <value>no</value>
    <Parameter>Result_Name</Parameter>
    <value>Google_Results</value>
 </Enviroment>
```

The code I am using to read this xml file is here.

```
public class ReadXML {
static String value;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,IOException {

File file = new File("path of the file");   
FileInputStream fileInput =new FileInputStream(file);   
Properties prop =new Properties();

//prop.load(fileInput);
prop.loadFromXML(fileInput); 

fileInput.close();  
Enumeration enumKeys=prop.keys();

while(enumKeys.hasMoreElements()){
    //String node = "Environment";
    String subnode= "Parameter";
    if(((String) enumKeys.nextElement()).contains(subnode)){
        value = prop.getProperty(subnode);
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
return ;
}
```

- When I am using `prop.load(fileInput)`, output is printed as `null` thrice for the three parameter values, I believe.
- But if I use `prop.loadFromXML(fileInput)`, `InvalidPropertiesFormatException` is shown.

Please help..Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Your xml file root tag is ="Enviroment". but in your code, you look for:  "Environment". there is missspeling

Comment: Thanks..@Mahsum I corrected that but it still shows that output as `null`

Comment: Is xml file you present correct? When i run it, got different error about not valid?

Comment: @Mahsum Xml file is correct. Please let me know what is the error you got. For me it always ends up in null

Comment: i got following error for prop.loadFromXML(fileInput);   => Exception in thread "main" java.util.InvalidPropertiesFormatException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 14; Element type "Environment" must be declared.

Comment: yeah.I got the same error,mentioned this in the post as well.

Answer (score 0):

The error in the properties format can be checked via xmllint:

```
xmllint foo.properties
```

In this case, the closing tag is:

```
</Enviroment>
```

but needs to be:

```
</Environment>
```

**References**

- [Class Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.InputStream-)